# Update fields in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a parents table, children and a fundings table. Children table has parent_id, fundings table has child_id. Parent applies for funding for various activities for his/her children. Each child can have more than one funding application. The amount_remaining field in children table is default $400 for each child. In the fundings table, there is a field amount_requested for the funding activity. Once the status field in the funding table is changed to approved the amount_requested is subtracted from the amount_remaining for the particular child. How is this possible. Please help me. I tried the steps below but it doesn't work.

child.rb

```
after_save do
        if status_changed? && status == 'Approved'
          amount_remaining = child.amount_remaining - funding.amount_requested
          child.update_attributes(amount_remaining: amount_remaining)
        end
    end
```

schema for funding table

```
create_table "fundings", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "type_of_activity"
    t.integer "amount_requested"
    t.integer "child_id"
    t.string "status"
end
```

schema for children table

```
create_table "children", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "firstname"
    t.string "lastname"
    t.integer "parent_id"
    t.integer "amount_remaining"
end
```

_form.html.erb(funding application form)

```
<div class = "form-group">
        <div class="control-label col-sm-2">
          <%= form.label :amount_requested, class: "required" %>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
          <%= form.text_field :amount_requested, required: true %>
        </div>
      </div> 
      <div class = "form-group">
        <div class="control-label col-sm-2">
          <%= form.label :status %>
        </div>
      <% if current_user.superadmin? %>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
          <%= form.select :status,['Pending', 'Approved', 'Declined'], {}, id: "sample-status-select", class: "form-control" %>
        </div>
      <% else %>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
          <%= form.select :status,['Pending', 'Approved', 'Declined'], {class: "form-control"}, {:disabled => true} %>
        </div>
      </div>
      <% end %>
```

Comment: when you say it doesn't work, do you mean you get an error ? is the logic not behaving correctly ?

Comment: @Subash I get an error. I am not able to create child. undefined method error

Comment: Can you please post your undefined method error to the original question

Comment: @MarkMerritt undefined method `status_changed?' for #<Child:0x00007f8f783ea5a8>

Comment: Have you defined a `status_changed?` method? If so, in what file?

Comment: @MarkMerritt no I have not defined it. Have I written the code under correct model? because status is a field in fundings table not in children table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As `child_id` is present in `Funding` model so,

in `funding.rb`

```
   belongs_to :child

    after_save do
      if status_changed? && status == 'Approved'
        if child.amount_remaining.to_f > funding.amount_requested.to_f
          amount_remaining = child.amount_remaining - funding.amount_requested
          child.update_column(:amount_remaining, amount_remaining)
        else
          errors.add(:insufficient_amount, "Insufficient amount!")
          raise ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid.new(self)
        end
      end
    end
```

You should `approve` funding only if `child.amount_remaining.to_f > funding.amount_requested.to_f`.

Comment: Here `after_save` callback will cause recursion. Instead of `update_attribute` you can use `update_column` to prevent recursion.

Comment: @AjayBarot Alright, thanks for point me out in right direction. :)

Comment: @Gabbar how can I assign a initial default value of $400 to child field amount_remaining?

Comment: @NAVROOPSINGHSIDHU Well there are two ways i figure out to set default value to 1) either set it to database level i.e at the column creation time set to default value 400 . 2) While you create children at controller just set it to 400. you can prefer any of these, i would suggest you to use 2nd one cause in future you can modify this easily.

Comment: @NAVROOPSINGHSIDHU At db level `add_column :amount_remaining, :children, :integer,  :default => 400`

Comment: @Gabbar i have a general_settings table where I have fields t.integer "amount_current_year", t.integer "amount_next_year". What I want is amount_current_year should correspond to amount_remaining in children table. and by the end of the year amount_next_year should be transfer to amount_current_year and then that value should correspond to amount_remaining in children table.  I want the fields amount_current_year and amount_next_year to be editable. Is it possible?

Comment: @Gabbar The code didnt work. I approved an application for child but the amount_requested did not reduce from amount_remaining.

Comment: @NAVROOPSINGHSIDHU do you get any error ? or could you use debugger to track it at model?

Comment: @Gabbar I dont get any error. But the amount_remaining doesn.'t reduce

Comment: @NAVROOPSINGHSIDHU can you check what was `funding.amount_requested` was it 0 or nil?  is that the reason this was't reduce?

Comment: @Gabbar how can I check ?

Comment: @NAVROOPSINGHSIDHU you should know how to use `debugger`. just put debugger before that line where you want to pause application and check the params.

Comment: @Gabbar require 'pry';binding.pry in funding model. This is what I get [2] pry(#<Funding>)> amount_requested
=> 100
[3] pry(#<Funding>)> amount_remaining
=> nil
[4] pry(#<Funding>)>

Comment: @NAVROOPSINGHSIDHU :D hopefully you got the issue? let me explain `amount_remaining` is nil so the condition `child.amount_remaining.to_f > funding.amount_requested.to_f` i.e `0.0 > 100.0` will return false and it wont update any column. to reflect changes you should have amount_remaning > amount_requested.. did you get it?

Comment: @Gabbar Yes I got it. But the amount_remaining is 400. and amount_requested is 100. Why doesnt it reflect amount_remaining to be 400? <Child id: 9, firstname: "ABC", lastname: "XYZ", dateofbirth: "1992-11-05", gender: "Male", created_at: "2018-07-06 14:56:46", updated_at: "2018-07-06 14:57:20", parent_id: 20, amount_remaining: 400>

Comment: @NAVROOPSINGHSIDHU Is the child is with 9 assocaited with the funding for which you are going to approve?  cause `[3] pry(#<Funding>)> amount_remaining => nil` which mean  for this `funding.child.amount_remaining` is nil. do you get it?

Comment: @Gabbar Yes funding approved and child with ID-9 are associated.

Comment: @NAVROOPSINGHSIDHU then it should not be nil. just do some r &d otherwise all good .

Comment: @Gabbar Okay I ll try. Thankyou

Comment: @Gabbar using 'pry if I check child.amount_remaining then it shows 400. But if just do amount_remaining it shows nil.

Comment: @NAVROOPSINGHSIDHU well we have to use `child.amount_remaining` so `amount_remaining` has no sense. please do some r & d , i dn't know your exact code. something went wrong at controller side

Comment: @NAVROOPSINGHSIDHU were you able to solve this issue?